# Inserting link tag with integrity and crossorigin attribute issue

Tags: javascript, html, cors, tags

Trying to insert css document with Javascript, however I receive error saying that request has to be CORS enabled. Is there a way to deal with it?

Here is the code:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css';
link.integrity = 'sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ';
link.crossorigin = 'anonymous';
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `crossorigin` (not a valid `HTMLLinkElement` attribute) to `crossOrigin` (note the capital "O"). Remember that HTML element properties are generally spelled in camel case (first word lower case with all subsequent words having their first letter capitalized) in Javascript.

```js
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css';
link.integrity = 'sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ';
link.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
document.head.appendChild(link);
```